# How to proceed related BindingSources when DataSource is empty

Tags: c#, data-binding, datasource, bindingsource

I would like to ask for advice. I meet this model situation:

- BindingSource headOfFamillyBS, its DataSources is List of objects `List<FamillyResources>`
- This object FamillyResources have properties, among others, `List<FreeTimeActivities>`
- Than I have two other BindingSources, one `freeTimeActivitiesBS`, which have DataSource and DisplayMember solved by DataBinding this way:

  ```
  this.freeTimeActivitiesBS.DataBindings.Add("DataSource", headOfFamillyBS, "view_frTmActvts");
  ```

than

```
this.freeTimeActivitiesBS.DisplayMember = "view_shortName";
```

The problem is:
When I call on `List<FamillyResources>` method .Clear(), it has no items, moreover property view_frTmActvts (which return list) is of course empty (because no items in source list - in **headOfFamillyBS**). Than BindingSource **freeTimeActivitiesBS** goes throw exception:

> DataBinding cannot find a row in the list that is suitable for all
>   bindings.

1. Is there any elegant way, how to handle situation, that LIST properties *of top* BindingSource, which other BindingSource has as theirs DataSource, is null?
2. Should I manual handle **ListChanged** event of **headOfFamillyBS** and check if List is empty, than Clear bindings to all other *connected* BindigSources? This will be pretty slow in case of houndreds or thousands items in source list.

Thanks for any advices!